# How do I get the initial configuration of my Azure role?

Tags: windows, azure, cloud

Suppose I deploy an Azure role supplying a service package and a service configuration. Then I change the configuration one or more times without redeploying the role.

Is it possible to get the initial configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [RoleEnvironment API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.aspx) only reflects the current values.
You could handle the [RoleEnvironment.Changing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.changing.aspx) event and keep track of the configuration changes from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the service configuration in a number of ways:

- Using the management portal

  1. Click on the deployment (it must in Ready state!)
  2. Click on "Configure" - edit the configuration.
     [image]
- Using the Manamgement REST API's [Change Deployment Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460809.aspx) method.

If you go for second option, you can either create your own classes or use, for example [this NuGet package](http://nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceManagement.Library).

However I don't think (I'm not aware of a method) you can get the initial service configuration once it has been changed.